# Keystone.js and tinyMCE change <img> and <a> tags to [img] and [a] text

Tags: html, tinymce, keystonejs

When I make a blog post and put anchor or image tags in it via the tinyMCE buttons it shows up as:

```
[a]text[/a]
```

instead of:

```
<a href="...">text</a>
```

This happens even when I manually put in html tags. This wouldn't be a problem if everything rendered but instead when I look at the blog post I can see these converted html tags as text. I tried changing some of the tinyMCE settings:

- valid_elements : '*[*]',
- cleanup_on_startup: false,
- verify_html: false,
- cleanup: false,
- convert_urls: false,
- valid_children: .....

Nothing I do seems to help. Is there anyway to stop this from happening? Any help is hugely appreciated!

Comment: Does this happen in TinyMCE at the moment you enter the data or only after you save the content and look at the "rendered" blog post?

Comment: Thanks Micheal, this was my fault. While I may have skimmed the plugins I was using 20 times it just never registered that I had copy and pasted in a bulletin board plugin into my keystone.init.

Answer (score 1):

This question got answered somewhere else. I just had to remove bbcode from my list of tinyMCE plugins in keystone.init. I feel pretty silly. So my wysiwyg settings look like this now:

```
'wysiwyg cloudinary images': true,
'wysiwyg override toolbar': false,
'wysiwyg menubar': true,
'wysiwyg skin': 'lightgray',
'wysiwyg additional buttons': 'searchreplace visualchars,'
 + ' charmap ltr rtl pagebreak paste, forecolor backcolor,'
 +' emoticons media, preview print ',
'wysiwyg additional plugins': 'example, table, advlist, anchor,'
 + ' autolink, autosave, charmap, contextmenu, '
 + ' directionality, emoticons, fullpage, hr, media, pagebreak,'
 + ' paste, preview, print, searchreplace, textcolor,'
 + ' visualblocks, visualchars, wordcount, legacyoutput',
'wysiwyg images': true,
```

Previously I had bbcode under 'wysiwyg additional plugins'.